# Iphone 14 in Hungary - Budapest comes with physical sim or e-sim only?

Tags: iphone, sim, esim

Iphone 14 in Hungary-Budapest comes with physical sim or e-sim only ? As I want to buy one

Answer (score 1):

All non-US iPhone models have a physical SIM card slot.